# File not recognized: File truncated GCC error

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

I'm trying to compile a simple "Hello World" program in Linux using Eclipse, but I always get this:

```
Building target: hello
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "hello"  ./src/hello.o   
./src/hello.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Just remove the object file.

This error most likely appeared after the previous build was interrupted and object file was not generated completely.

Comment: Is there any tips to avoid this for incremental build? Our pull request build is incremental build, and new commit will cancel the old running one. I often meet this issue and that will block our CI system.

Comment: In my case said object file does not exist still it's saying failed because of truncated .o file

Comment: Your CI system should not run incremental builds. Developers cannot afford to wait for a clean build after every edit; conversely a CI system cannot afford the lack of reliability inherent to incremental builds.

Comment: @markuscornelius, please be respectful and do not put words in my mouth. What I am saying is that with incremental CI builds the cost of false positives and false negatives is higher than the savings resulting from more frequent builds. I have quantified and confirmed this with several clients, however I must admit my sample is biased toward larger teams. If your experience differs I'd be curious to hear more details.

Comment: Just for those who are facing this issue after following the step mentioned in the answer, If you compiled your code using some build system like `cmake` you will have some more files along with the object file. So just remove all of them ie do `rm <objectfile name>.o.*`

Answer (score 21):

Just as an info if someone comes around here.

Another problem (with the same error) could be, that you are using [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/) for faster compilation. In this case, the corrupt *.o file is there as well. So for that reason you have to clean the cache with

`ccache -C` (note the upper case C!)

Wasted me hours the first time ;-)

Comment: You might prefer not to blow away your entire cache. Instead (from the man page) you can remove the broken object file from your build directory, then build with `CCACHE_RECACHE` set.

Comment: That´s true, but usually you build with several threads (e.g. -j 10) and if you for example run out of disc space 10 random object files will be corrupt. So it´s likely that you compile 9 times and every time the compiler will stop on another file (which you then can delete from the cache). But if that´s not the case, your suggestions is of course right.

Comment: This saved my day, deleting the object file mentioned in the error wouldn't help in any way.

Comment: For me it was ccache -cC

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
g++  -o "hello"  ./src/hello.o  
should be ./src/hello.(c | cpp | cc depending on your language type)
```

Comment: In that directory I have only hello.cc so I dont know why it says there hello.o

Comment: @vbX is it Default make file generated by eclipse ?