# Using 32 bit .a library file in 64 bit linux machine

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, .a

I am trying to use 32 bit .a files in a 64 bit machine. I compiled source code using gcc -m32 option. It gave following error

```
gcc -m32 *.c -Llib -lquanser_communications -Iinclude -o prg.o`In file included from /usr/include/wchar.h:27:0,
             from include/quanser_types.h:16,
             from include/quanser_communications.h:16,
             from include/quanser_stream.h:11,
             from stream_client.c:3:/usr/include/features.h:374:25:
```

`fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory`

After searching I got to this and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498237/compile-program-for-32bit-on-64bit-linux-os-causes-fatal-error) and installed libx32gcc-4.8-dev and libc6-dev-i386 packages.

After installing those packages and running compilation gives following error

```
gcc -m32 *.c -Llib -lquanser_communications -Iinclude -o prg.o
lib/libquanser_communications.a: file not recognized: File truncated
```

How could I fix this issue ? 
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File not recognized: File truncated GCC error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713894/file-not-recognized-file-truncated-gcc-error)

Comment: Is the output from `objdump -x libquanser_communications.a` ok?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting this error because your libquanser_communications is 64-bit and not 32-bit. You can't compile 32 bit against 64 bit code.

If you compiled libqunaser yourself, compile it with the -m32 flag (recursively, until you're done with all dependencies).

If not, get the 32 bit version of it

Comment: Thanks for your help. Those libraries are from 3rd party and they are 32 bit while my machine is 64 bit. I tried compiling without -m32 flag, but it gives the same error saying file is truncated.