# libhdf5_serial_hl.so: file not recognized: File truncated

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, caffe, ubuntu-18.04

What does this error mean, during [caffe](https://github.com/tianzhi0549/CTPN) compilation ? How shall I fix it?

Commands:

```
cd /home/aegono/CTPN/caffe
sudo make -j && make pycaffe
```

Output:

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libhdf5_serial_hl.so: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:515: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
```

I think the file is corrupted, so I tried reinstalling the package by issuing the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libhdf5-serial-dev` with no luck. the error still occurs.

Comment: Try `make_clean` and then `make` again. 

Just remove the object file.

This error most likely appeared after the previous build was interrupted and object file was not generated completely. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17789868/4980722

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf The error still occured.

Comment: Can you tell me how to reproduce this error?